# Creating functions that raise errors in Oracle APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am on my 2nd week of using Oracle APEX 19 and I am nearly finished developing a novice level application that allows users to create/update/delete product families. I used an Interactive Grid but now I need to create a function somewhere (validation? process?) that calls on the support package I created in JDev. The function in the package checks the table to see if the family already exists. If it does, I need APEX to raise an error instantly upon entering NOT after saving.

The name of the Region is PF and the column in question is called product_family. APEX doesn't handle BIND VARIABLES (:pf) so I am aware that the syntax changes but I do not know how that would change the PL/SQL function below.

I created a Validation
Type: PL/SQL Function Body (RETURN BOOLEAN)

```
BEGIN
   IF product_families.product_family_exists(:pf.product_family) THEN
      MSG_ALERT (
                 'Product family previously exists.'
                ,'E'
                ,TRUE
                );
    END IF;
END;
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to raise an error instantly upon entering a product family in the grid, if it already exists? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify. In a standard validation you can test column values with the :COLUMN syntax, and perhaps use the error type that returns an error message, instead of boolean.

```
IF product_families.product_family_exists(:product_family) THEN
 return 'Product family previously exists.';
END IF;
```

Where is Msg_alert from? IT seems very forms-like.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. This solved the syntax error and I now receive this error notification when the system tries to save a record where the prod_family exists. One minor problem is when the user needs to UPDATE a record (obviously with a prod_family that already exists), this error notification is raised and the system refuses to save a modified record. This error should only be raised upon creating a record, not updating it. Is there a property for this in APEX or does the code need to change?

Comment: True, and based on the function name/error I would ask - why isn't this just a database constraint on the database that is captured natively by the application error handler?

Comment: Hey, Scott. I would like to try this as a possible solution, I still can't edit or update a record because of the error I've added. I am trying to articulate exactly what you mean so I may duplicate the effort and hopefully have a solution to this new problem. Mind elaborating?

Comment: I mean your validation should be relevant when you're inserting/update data outside of APEX. The procedure name sounds like something that could be a unique index on your table. So if you have that index, the db would do the validation for you, all you need to do is translate the exception - APEX should catch it for you.

Comment: Interesting. So in order to translate the exception, a validation doesn't need to be created, right? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can create an error handling function, and an exception lookup table. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.html#GUID-2CD75881-1A59-4787-B04B-9AAEC14E1A82 Then you can try other things http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/enhance-oracle-apex-error-handling-function-logger.html

Comment: Thank you, Scott. I created this function in the form of a package in JDev and then referenced it in APEX in the Error-Handling section in the properties attributes. I did this to change the Child Constraint error message (2292). I appreciate all of your help! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Scott. Uh sorry to bother you again. I am trying to gain some deeper knowledge on the error handling function and what else it is capable of doing. Can you access server name, ip address, session id and app_user or can these be passed in as parameters? Does it return an error stack? Is the session id persistent? Any chance you can point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a package/procedure/function that is being called, you can use the APEX_ERROR package to raise an error and prevent any changes from being committed.

Try adding this to your code and you should see the error message appear in the browser when the code is called

```
apex_error.add_error (p_message            => 'Test error message',
                      p_display_location   => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification);
```

P.S. If you are building a validation on an interactive grid, you can reference the column value like `:PRODUCT_FAMILY` in your validation.

Comment: Instead of using (:pf.product_family), I used (:product_family) which I believe is putting me on the right track. However, now I am getting an error saying the MSG_ALERT needs to be declared. My syntax is bad somewhere.

Comment: Also, did you mean to add that code to my package in jdeveloper or to my code in APEX? Because my boss very seriously wants the error to raise as soon as the "family" has been entered.

Comment: If you are working in an Oracle package, procedure, or function that is called by your APEX validation, you will want to use `apex_error.add_error`. In the APEX validation if your type of validation is PL/SQL function then either return the boolean to trigger the error or the error text that should be displayed to the user.

Comment: Hi EJ, is it possible to create a validation and use apex_error.add_error for a constraint? I need to modify the 'Child Record Found' error into a message more suitable for the users. I think I am looking at the correct documentation to do this from Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_error.htm#AEAPI2209